# How to itereate through array when i use reduce array function in typescript?

Tags: angular

I have this code where i group array:

```
  let result = this.events.reduce( function(r,a){  r[a.item] = r[a.item] || [];
        r[a.item].push(a);
        return r;
      }, Array());
        //this.events.map((event)=>{ console.log(event,'e'); this.items[event.item] = event; console.log('itemssss',this.items)});
        this.items = result;
        console.log(this.items);
```

Result that i get is this :
[image]

How can i iterate now this two arrays in html ?? Any suggestion?

So i want first to display that from first array and then to display data from second array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you want to keep the arrays separated:**

You can iterate two times over them. Firstly on the main array and on the different arrays it contains:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items">
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let order of item">
                <!-- You can access objects properties here -->
                {{ order.statusName }} // <-- for example
            <li>
        </ul>
    <li>
</ul>
```

**Other solution:**

You can also merge them before looping on them :

So change `this.items = result` to `this.items = this.items.concat(result);`

After that, you can iterate over `this.items`. For example:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items">
        ...
        {{ item.statusName }}
        ...
    </li>
</ul>
```